# Why doesn't the function return a value to another variable than the one used as operand?

Tags: c, function, matrix, pass-by-reference, gaussian-process

I am making a gauss elimination program and the function that i use is applied on a matrix in the form of a static array that is a member of a struct MATRIX. I wanted to return the new eliminated row-echelon form of the matrix as a new struct variable. Let 1 be the matrix i set to eliminate, i want to make matrix 2 hold matrix's 1 row-echelon form.

This is the struct definition that holds a static amount of variables (i've set it to `struct matrix MATRIX[10]`):

```
struct matrix{
    float array[k][l];
    char line[k];
    char column[l];
    int inversity;
};
```

And this is the function segment:

```
float gauss(struct matrix MATRIX[],int n){
    int row=0,flag=0;
    while(row<k){
        //LEFTMOST NON-ZERO COLUMN ID 
        int j=0,cid,rid;
        flag=0;
        while((j<l)&&(flag!=1)){
            int i=row;    
            //printf("i value is: %d\n",i);
            while((i<k)&&(flag!=1)){    
                if(MATRIX[n].array[i][j]!=0){    
                    flag=1;    
                    cid=j; 
                    rid=i;    
                }    
                i++;    
            } 
            j++;
        }//printf("Leftmost column with at least a non-zero char is: %d and its location is: %d,%d\n",cid,cid,rid);
    //SWAPPING WITH CEILING ROW
        if(flag!=0)
            for(int j=0; j<l; j++){
                    float temp=MATRIX[n].array[rid][j];
                    MATRIX[n].array[rid][j]=MATRIX[n].array[row][j];
                    MATRIX[n].array[row][j]=temp; 
            }
        //printf("Swapping done:\n"); printmatrix(MATRIX,1);
    //SETTING LEAD 1
        float temp=MATRIX[n].array[row][cid];
            if(temp!=0){
                for(int j=0; j<l; j++){
                    MATRIX[n].array[row][j]/=temp;
                }
            }//printf("Set lead:\n"); printmatrix(MATRIX,1);
    //OPERATION SEGMENT
            for(int i=(row+1); i<k; i++){
                float temp=MATRIX[n].array[i][cid];
                //printf("temp is %.2f\n",temp);
                    for(int j=0; j<l; j++){
                        //printf("sub factor is %.2f\n",(-1*temp*MATRIX[n].array[row][j]));
                        MATRIX[n].array[i][j]+=(-1*temp*MATRIX[n].array[row][j]);
                    }//printmatrix(MATRIX,1);
            }//printf("Done operations:\n"); printmatrix(MATRIX,1);
            row++;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<l; j++)
            if(MATRIX[n].array[i][j]==(-1*0)) MATRIX[n].array[i][j]=0;
    printf("Done final operations:\n"); printmatrix(MATRIX,n);
    return MATRIX[n+1].array[k][l];
}
```

After that i use the following to assign the new matrix to a new struct variable:

```
MATRIX[n+1].array[k][l]=gauss(MATRIX,rem);
```

Comment: `return MATRIX[+].array[k][l];` Does that compile with the `+`?

Comment: `gauss(MATRIX[n].array[][]) = MATRIX[n+1].array[][]` You cannot assign to a return value of a function. Please [edit] your question and explain what you want to achieve using an example.

Comment: A return value is just that - a *value*.  You can't assign something else to a *value*.  Assigning `72` to `4` makes no sense.

Comment: You can't use `[]` in an expression. `[]` can only be used in an array declaration with an initializer, it means to get the array size from the number of initializers. So `MATRIX[n].array[][]` makes no sense.